# Tish'a Ushmonim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred eighty-nine?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the Raavad's figures, the era of the Rabbanan Savorai lasted 189 years, from [4260](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36858&st=&pgnum=60) to [4449](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36858&st=&pgnum=61). Though he then summarizes it as 187 years.

Answer (score 5):

There are 189 words in the Aseret Hadibrot on the second luchot (Parsh Va'etchanan)